# How do I read the public key from a signed C# exe

Tags: c#, public-key, x509, signtool

I'm signing a dot net exe using

```
signcode.exe with an spc/pvk combo
```

The file needs to read its own Public Key at runtime in order to verify some data. I've gone down a number of different avenues.

I've tried

```
X509Certificate executingCert = X509Certificate.CreateFromSignedFile(exe);
```

executingCert is then null. I'm guessing signcode isn't creating an X509 signed file, though if there's a switch to change that I'm happy to go that way.

*edited*
Turns out the above does work.... I had my null check backwards (!= != ==) :)

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
string exe = asm.Location;
X509Certificate executingCert = X509Certificate.CreateFromSignedFile(exe); 

if (executingCert != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Assembly is signed");
    byte[] assemblyKey = executingCert.GetPublicKey();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SignCode (for .Net 1.0 and 1.1) uses Authenticode signing, which as far as I'm aware, lacks a .Net Framework managed interface. You will likely need to use P/Invoke to call routines in Win32 API such as those found in this [KB article: How To Get Information from Authenticode Signed Executables](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323809/en-us). Likely you'll need to use [CryptQueryObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380264(VS.85).aspx) which will get you the
certificate, which you will then likely have to find another routine to pull the public key from.

Check out this related StackOverflow question which has a lot of answers: [WinVerifyTrust to check for a specific signature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072540/winverifytrust-to-check-for-a-specific-signature)

Comment: Thanks looks like that should work if I can pull off all the p/invoking

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that:

```
Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().GetPublicKey()
```

I used GetEntryAssembly in that case, but of course you can call the method on any loaded assembly.

Comment: That is reading the public key of a strong name not of a digital signature based on certificates!