# How do I read the digital signature information from a signed .Net assembly?

Tags: c#, x509certificate, digital-signature, signed, authenticode

I am writing an assembly information application to be used in our software build process and am trying to read the digital signature information from a signed .Net assembly.

I want to do in my C# code what Windows Explorer can do by right-clicking a signed assembly and selecting the "Digital Signatures" tab and then clicking the Details button. e.g.

[image: Windows 7 Explorer can do by right-clicking file properties]

[image: Digital signature details]

Has anyone got an idea how to do this programmatically in C#? I am currently using the [Mono Cecil library](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil) to get the rest of the information from the assembly. Your help will be most appreciated.

Comment: What you show is `Authenticode` signature, applicable to all PE files. There also exists `strongnaming`, .NET-specific signature format. Strongnaming is done using a keypair, not a certificate, consequently you can't extract any useful information from the strongnamed assembly. Doing search for `Authenticode` on StackOverflow will give you plenty of useful information.

Comment: [Possibly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/301024/validate-authenticode-signature-on-exe-c-without-capicom) [related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3281057/get-timestamp-from-authenticode-signed-files-in-net) questions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I read the public key from a signed C# exe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3722610/how-do-i-read-the-public-key-from-a-signed-c-sharp-exe)

Comment: That did the trick, the X509Certificate.CreateFromSignedFile(exe) works like a charm. However, it raises an exception rather null as shown in the "How do I read the public key from a signed C# exe" link.

Answer (score 6):

The Mono project provides source code for both [`signcode`](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/tools/security/signcode.cs) and [`chktrust`](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/tools/security/chktrust.cs) that you can re-use inside your own application (open source, MIT X11 licensed).

Both use `Mono.Security.dll` assembly (which works under Windows, not just Linux and OSX) and include a quite [complete Authenticode support](https://github.com/mono/mono/tree/master/mcs/class/Mono.Security/Mono.Security.Authenticode).

Answer (score 1):

From [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3731122/361177) :

> SignCode (for .Net 1.0 and 1.1) uses Authenticode signing, which as
>   far as I'm aware, lacks a .Net Framework managed interface.

Hopefully, it's looks like that some Nuget package implement it:

- https://github.com/vcsjones/AuthenticodeExaminer
- https://github.com/vcsjones/AuthenticodeLint
- https://www.nuget.org/packages/CodeFluentRuntimeClient/