# Get Timestamp of signature in X509Certificate in C#

Tags: c#, x509certificate

Where can I get the date and the time of a signature?
Now I get the certificate information with this code:

```
var signer = X509Certificate2.CreateFromSignedFile(fileName);
var certificate = new X509Certificate2(signer);
```

And I can read some properties, but I cannot find WHEN the file was signed.

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure that that is recorded?  You can of course get the NotBefore/NotAfter stamps quite easily.

Comment: Yes. It is recorder. I opened the file with a software that checks digital signature and it show the Signature date.

Comment: Can you document that?  Name+version of that software, screenshot maybe. Also: do all certificates have this date? Check a few.

Comment: No, it is not recorded in the X509Certificate. You are thinking of something else, a signature on a Windows file that follows some standard like Authenticode(old name, I have no idea what they call it nowdays). That uses a version of PKCS#7 to store the certificate as well as a second signature by a timestamping authority containing a timestamp.

Comment: Thank you James. You are right, but I cannot find the method to extract this information neither using the System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs library

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I read the digital signature information from a signed .Net assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10549836/how-do-i-read-the-digital-signature-information-from-a-signed-net-assembly)