# How do I programmatically check that the code signing of my EXE is valid at program start?

Tags: windows, winapi, certificate

Windows Platform (8/10/11)

I always sign my compiled exe files with my own official digital certificate.

Im looking for an example to check that the digital certificate of my EXE file is still present & valid at the program start.

Some pseudo code what i want to archieve at program start:

1. get certificate data of the started exe process
2. if certificate not exist : exit prg
3. if certificate not valid : exit prg
4. if certificate owner not "John Doe" : exit prg

I guess there must be some win-apis to retrieve the certificate data of the current process...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WinVerifyTrust to check for a specific signature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072540/winverifytrust-to-check-for-a-specific-signature)

Comment: Why do you care? If someone has manipulated your EXE, then they could easily circumvent your signature check as well.

Comment: I suggest you could try to use [CertGetCertificateChain function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-certgetcertificatechain) to build a certificate chain and then use [CertVerifyCertificateChainPolicy function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-certverifycertificatechainpolicy) to check a certificate chain to verify its validity.